# How to convert types for specific columns in h2o dataframe?

Tags: h2o

Is there a way to convert the types of specific columns in an h2o dataframe? For example if all the columns are type `int` in some dataframe df, but would like to use one of the columns C of 1's and 0's as the sample responses for training, is there a way to do something like `df['C'].to_type('enum')`? Could find no such thing in the [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

- [.asfactor()](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html?highlight#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.asfactor) to convert to enum
- [.asnumeric()](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html?highlight#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.asnumeric) to convert to numeric
- [.ascharacter()](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html?highlight#h2o.frame.H2OFrame.ascharacter) to convert to a character

Comment: The docs don't seem to indicate that a specific column can be converted, only the entire frame. Is this true?

Comment: yes you can convert a column, please see our code examples in the user guide appendix, whenever there is a numeric column response column that needs to be converted to enum we apply .asfactor() to that single column. http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/x.html#example. hope this helps!

Comment: `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].asfactor()`. Similarly for the other two types.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've been able to do so far is to convert the h2o dataframe back to a pandas frame, then back to h2o while specifying new column types for the desired columns. Eg.

```py
frame_in_h2o = h2o.H2OFrame(
    frame_in_h2o.as_data_frame(), 
    column_types={
        u'C': u'enum'
    })
```